# Phidgets Temperature sensor using python code

Tags: python

I started learning python recently and there’s still some things I’m not too good at and don’t fully grasp, especially object oriented programing (oop). I need to write a python program for a Phidgets temperature sensor device using a Phidget InterfaceKit 8/8/8. I looked at  Phidgets’s sample code but it didn’t help me much.

This is part of the sample Phidgets python code. These events are used as parameters for the Phidgets class TemperatureSensor() later in the program.
What's mostly confusing is the 'e'. What is 'e'? Is it like 'self' or something else? What does e.device (and 
e.other words) mean/do?

Also if anyone has any advice how to write a python code for a Phidgets temperature sensor i would greatly appreciate it.

```
#Event Handler Callback Functions  
def TemperatureSensorAttached(e):  
    attached = e.device
    print("TemperatureSensor %i Attached!" % (attached.getSerialNum()))

def TemperatureSensorDetached(e):
    detached = e.device
    print("TemperatureSensor %i Detached!" % (detached.getSerialNum()))

def TemperatureSensorError(e):
    try:
        source = e.device
        if source.isAttached():
            print("TemperatureSensor %i: Phidget Error %i: %s" %        (source.getSerialNum(), e.eCode, e.description))
    except PhidgetException as e:
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))

def TemperatureSensorTemperatureChanged(e):
    try:
        ambient = temperatureSensor.getAmbientTemperature() 
    except PhidgetException as e:                                 
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
        ambient = 0.00

    source = e.device
    print("TemperatureSensor %i: Ambient Temp: %f -- Thermocouple %i     temperature: %f -- Potential: %f" % (source.getSerialNum(), ambient, e.index, e.temperature, e.potential))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `e` variable is passed as an argument to the event handlers. It is an event object, containing information about the event.

Event handlers are often used for asynchronous programming. It makes it possible to write programs that react to external changes such as a user clicking a button or a sensor reading changing. Most of the time, you don't need to handle all possible events. Instead you write an event handler and *register* it with the event source. In your case the event source is a device, and event handlers are registered using calls like `device.setOnAttachHandler(AttachHandler)`.

The `TemperatureSensorTemperatureChanged`, for example, is triggered when the sensor reading is updated (or on a regular basis).

`e.something` is simply data related to the event, passed to the event handler. It seems like `e.temperature` could be useful.

It seems like you are on the right track, you are reading example code and documentation so you will figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This code was intended for the Humidity+Temperature sensor, so it was not tested on the simpler temperature only sensor. Moreover, it is made with the newer phidget22. I hope it helps:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Phidget22.Devices.TemperatureSensor import *
from Phidget22.Net import *

TempArray = []
i = 0

while 1:
    ct = TemperatureSensor()
    try:
        ct.openWaitForAttachment(500)
    except PhidgetException as error:
        break
    TempArray.append(ct)

for i in TempArray:
     print("Serial: %s Temperature: %0.2f°C" % (i.getDeviceSerialNumber(),   i.getTemperature()))
i.close()
```

The e in your code, as was explained above, is a handle for the event. I used a somewhat different approach to use as an instance of the temperature sensor object (only using the attach event). Both ways work.